# Database structure relational database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm creating the database for a small apartments management site.

Basically there will be a login form for users, where they will be able to insert their apartment, with description, photos. And since I will work with relational tables I want to be sure that I'm creating the database right. Can someone take a look and give their opinion?

```
USERS:
  - id_user;
  - username;
  - password;
  - email;

APARTMENTS:
  - id_apartment;
  - id_user;
  - title;
  - description;
  - map;
  - gallery;

GALLERY_IMAGES:
  - id_gallery;
  - id_apartment;
  - image;
```

Comment: What is the gallery field in apartments for? You don't need a key field there because you have it in the gallery_images table.

Comment: @chiborg May be `gallery` in `apartments` is a `boolean`. Though, I don't think it is required.

Comment: can an apartment had 2 owners or more?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your design is only going to allow for an "apartment" to be related to a single user.

I suggest that the primary key of each table be a single integer column named `id`.
And any foreign key references to that primary key would be named `tablename_id`.

You need to review the cardinality of the relationships.
Can a "user" be related to more than one "apartment"?
Can an "apartment" be related to more than one "user"?
Can an "image" be related to more than one "apartment"?
etc.

When we find a "many-to-many" relationship, we normally resolve that with a relationship table.

If an "apartment" can be related to more than one "user", given...

```
apartment (id PK, ... )

user (id PK, ... )
```

We would add a third table, with the combination of foreign keys unique

```
user_apartment ( user_id FK, apartment_id FK, UNIQUE KEY (user_id, apartment_id) )
```

---

You seem to have a concept of a "gallery" which is distinct from your concept of an "image". (Think in terms of instances that can be "uniquely identified" and that you want to store information about.)

Can an image be in more than one gallery?
Can a gallery have more than one image?
Can a gallery be related to more than one apartment?

If an image belongs to exactly one gallery, and a gallery is related to exactly one apartment, then I would implement as...

```
gallery (id PK, apartment_id FK, ... )  
image (id PK, gallery_id FK, ...)
```

Comment: usingid as the name for the id field is a SQl antipattern.

Comment: @HLGEM: using a column named `id` as the primary key for each table is a workable approach, which has some significant advantages. There are some difficulties as well. Those difficulties don't just disappear by using a name other than `id` for your primary key column.

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed your scenario: (I am guessing)

an apartment belongs to a user
an apartment has 0 or more images

Then why have you introduced the concept of a Gallery?

```
USERS:
- id_user;
- username;
- password;
- email;

APARTMENTS:
- id_apartment;
- id_user;
- title;
- description;
- map;

IMAGES:
- id_image
- id_apartment;
- image_path;
```

If this is the case then tbh the Gallery is in fact images of the apartment, I mean call it that on your GUI ...

Do some users have more than one apartment?